# How to run suite of Geb Tests in Grails app

Tags: grails, testing, functional-testing, geb

**I would like to run multiple Geb tests/spec using JUnit's funcionality**. Run in Grails app using `grails test-app -unit TestSuite` do not execute Spec tests. What is a right way?

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
     import org.junit.runners.Suite

         @RunWith(Suite.class)
         @Suite.SuiteClasses([
             HotelPageSpec.class,
             TourSearchSpec.class,
             MyToursSpec.class,

         ])

         public class TestSuite {
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will run all functional tests:

```
grails test-app functional
```

This will run only one test suite

```
grails test-app functional: TestSuite
```

Tested on spock tests on grails 2.3.5
See the example [here](http://www.adavis.info/2014/04/grails-functional-testing-with-geb-and.html)

Comment: Thanks. But when I try to run TestSuite, no Spec is executed.

`Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/
.......
|Compiling 2 source files
.
|Server stopped
.........
|Tests PASSED - view reports`